# SPList Replacelink method

Tags: splist

I am trying to find and replace url links in sharepoint lists. The ReplaceLink method(SPList class) does the job for straight forward urls like "www.google.com/test" but truncates the url parameter for links like "www.google.com?search=badReplace" . 
  Is there a workaround for this method ? I found SPLink has a url and urlparameter properties but they don't have an associated setter method. Any Suggestions,thoughts would be helpful